# How to query to get rank of a row?

Tags: mysql, sql, rank

I am creating a photo ranking system. Basically, I have three main fields - won, lost, howmanyplayed.

Let's say I have three photos

```
Photo  Won  Lost  Played
-------------------------
A      3    2     5
B      1    4     5
C      3    2     5
```

I am going to write a query to get rank of each photos. The problem is, Photo A and Photo C have exactly same record. How do make a query that returns 1 for both Photo A and C?

```
Photo  Won  Lost  Played  Rank
-------------------------------
A      3    2     5       1
C      3    2     5       1
B      1    4     5       ?
```

**Added on 3/17/11**

I have changed the table structure a little bit

so now I have "vote_ratio" field instead of "played". "vote_ratio" holds value of "vote_win" / "vote_lose".

so the table must be revised as

```
Photo   Won   Lost   Ratio
A       3     2      1.5 
B       1     4      0.25 
C       3     2      1.5
```

What I want to do :

1. query only "Photo A" and get the rank of it.
2. query all the records and display the rank of each record.

I can do #2 by the following query.

```
"select * from table order by ratio desc"
```

but there is a problem again. Photo A and C have same ratio. I need to make both of them rank #1.

Comment: what your query is at this moment ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "return 1"? Return a single row? Return a row for each one?

Comment: you question is not clear. How's your ranking system? Whats your table structure?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have analytic support, which is what the DENSE_RANK function would return if setup properly. But it's unclear how you are expecting A & C to have a rank of one - based on the value of the `won` column?  Shouldn't it matter how large the `played` value is with respect to the number won?

Comment: @all // I am really sorry for the insufficient information. I will post more information when I get home. I will also test for bensiu and ggregoire's solutions!

Comment: @OMG Ponies // you're right. So I changed 'played' rahnk to 'ratio' now.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean "return 1" as return 1 record of ranking ? -> not tested, however it could combination of GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT like this:

```
SELECT Won, Lost, Played, GROUP_CONCAT( photo, ', ' ) AS photos
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Won, Lost, Played
```

Answer (score 1):

not tested

```
SELECT *
FROM photos
ORDER BY (played/lost)
```

I think it returns :

```
Photo A // rank1
Photo C // rank1
Photo B // rank2
```

Comment: I think you meant `ORDER BY (played/lost) DESC`. But... what if there are no losses?

Comment: it only works for a collection of rows. I need to query a certain row by its id then get the rank of it.